# Different instruction address shown in ltrace and objdump

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64, ltrace

I use ltrace and objdump to analyse the simple code below. But I find there is a difference on instruction address shown between ltrace and objdump.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello";
    return 0;
}
```

As the following info, you can see that the address of [call std::basic_ostream] is [0x400789] in ltrace.   (0x400789 is the address of the instruction "call", not std::basic_ostream)

```
binary@binary-VirtualBox:~/code/chapter5/test$ ltrace -i -C ./a.out
[0x4006a9] __libc_start_main(0x400776, 1, 0x7fff06c6ad28, 0x4007f0 <unfinished ...>
[0x4007b7] std::ios_base::Init::Init()(0x601171, 0xffff, 0x7fff06c6ad38, 160)             = 0
[0x4007cb] __cxa_atexit(0x400650, 0x601171, 0x601048, 0x7fff06c6ab00)                     = 0
[0x400789] std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)(0x601060, 0x400874, 0x7fff06c6ad38, 192) = 0x601060
[0x7f220180aff8] std::ios_base::Init::~Init()(0x601171, 0, 0x400650, 0x7f2201b96d10Hello)      = 0x7f2201f19880
[0xffffffffffffffff] +++ exited (status 0) +++
```

However, the address of [call std::basic_ostream] shown in objdump is [0x400784] and
another instruction [mov eax,0x0] is on [0x400789]. The same is true for other "call" instructions.

```
0000000000400776 <main>:
  400776:       55                      push   rbp
  400777:       48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
  40077a:       be 74 08 40 00          mov    esi,0x400874
  40077f:       bf 60 10 60 00          mov    edi,0x601060
  400784:       e8 d7 fe ff ff          call   400660 <_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc@plt>
  400789:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
  40078e:       5d                      pop    rbp
  40078f:       c3                      ret
```

I really want to know what causes the gap.
Thank you a lot.

Comment: As in, why don't the address of the function and the address you see in `ltrace` don't exactly match? It's probably in the middle of the function.

Comment: Those are return addresses (instruction after the `call` in the parent; ltrace can't know how long the instruction was that called a function, only the return address it got.  Or if it was tail-called, execution would have reached it from a `jmp` or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are return addresses (instruction after the `call` in the parent, the address which `call` pushes on the stack).

`ltrace` can't know how long the instruction was that called a function, e.g. `call reg` with a function pointer is only 2 bytes vs. 5 for `call rel32` vs. 6 for `call [RIP + rel32]` (memory-indirect call which GCC will use if you compile with `-fno-plt`.)

Or if it was tail-called, execution would have reached it from a `jmp` or something, so even on an ISA with fixed-length instructions like MIPS or AArch64, `ltrace` still couldn't reliably print where it was called from.  Best to not try to make too much stuff up and keep it simple, printing the address it can actually see on the callstack.